# How do I filter the sales grid in admin panel?

Tags: sales-order

This is my code:

```
  class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid extends 

        Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
        {

            public function __construct()
            {
                parent::__construct();
                $this->setId('sales_order_grid');
                $this->setUseAjax(true);
                $this->setDefaultSort('created_at');
                $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
                $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
            }
protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
        $collection->getSelect()->join('sales_flat_order', 'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order.entity_id',array('data_expeditie','moneda_comanda'));

        $collection->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array('created_at'=>'30.06.2015 21:41:02'));

        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
 protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
  $this->addColumn('created_at', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased On'),
            'index' => 'created_at',
            'filter_index'=>'main_table.created_at',
            'type' => 'datetime',
            'width' => '100px',
        ));
}
    }
```

I want my grid to show the last 30 days sales. 
This is the controller:

```
class Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{

    /**
     * Orders grid
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
            $this->_title($this->__('Sales'))->_title($this->__('Orders'));

            $from = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('-60 day'));
            $to = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('0 day'));
            $locale = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode();

            Mage::register('preparedFilter', array(
                //'store_id' => '1',
                //'status' => 'processing',
                'created_at' => array(
                    'from'=> new Zend_Date($from, null, $locale),
                    'to'=> new Zend_Date($to, null, $locale),
                    'locale' => $locale,
                    'orig_to' => Mage::helper('core')->formatDate($to),
                    'orig_from' => Mage::helper('core')->formatDate($from),
                    'datetime' => true
                )
            ));
        $this->_initAction()->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

how can i do that ?

Comment: Are you saying you want to restrict the orders to 30 days? By the way, **do not** edit core files, this is really bad practise.

Comment: Yes. by default ! it is not the core files it is extend in local/Mage/Adminhtml...